# custom wordpress php file relations not recognized

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, include

I am trying to do something quiet simple:
from file /inc/follow-event.php I am calling an ajax post request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { data:'asd'},
    url: "/wp-content/themes/cust/lib/follow_cat_event.php"
});
```

the file lib/follow_cat_event.php is:

```
<?php
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo $user->ID;
?>
```

and for some reason, the request returns error 500 because the follow_cat_event do not recognize wordpress functions even when it is included in functions.php:

```
include "lib/follow_cat_event.php";
```

EDIT UPDATE:

follow_cat_event.php:

```
<?php 
    add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
    function my_action_callback(){
        global $wpdb;
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        echo $user->ID;
        if ( isset($_GET['data']) ) {
        }
    }
?>
```

follow_cat.php:

```
function myFunction(){
    jQuery.post(
        "/wp-content/themes/geektime/lib/follow_cat_event.php",
        {
        action: "my_action",
        data: { data:'asd'},
        }
    );
}
```

still no luck...

Comment: If you are writing custom ajax functions, you should use AJAX the 'correct' way. Do some research on "ajax in wordpress."

Comment: Calling PHP files like that inside a WordPress theme does not mean WordPress functions are automatically loaded in it.

Comment: @Meschiany Don't send request to `/wp-content/themes/geektime/lib/follow_cat_event.php' your `wp_ajax` action won't work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you add your `/inc/follow-event.php` in your function.php, It won't be able to use wordpress functions in it. Because `/inc/follow-event.php` in itself doesn't come under the scope of wordpress function. You can create a plugin & try it that way.

Also Don't forget to add action while implementing AJAX with Wordpress default AJAX handler

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    action : "my_action"
    data: { data:'asd'}, 
    url: "<?php admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>" 
});
```

Now, Add a Plugin & *Activate* it.

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Wordpress AJAX
Author: Abhineet Verma
Version: 1.0
*/

function st_24388029(){
    // Do your stuff here
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'st_24388029' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'st_24388029' );
?>
```

This will allow you to make AJAX request in your Wordpress Frontend as well.

Comment: add_action( 'wp_ajax_st_24388029', 'st_24388029' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_st_24388029', 'st_24388029' );

Comment: @pmandell Please check [codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side) It says that _action_ in wp_ajax_(action) is what you send as parameter in your ajax request. Function name doesn't need to be same as the action.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, I'm trying to send **my_action** using **action** parameter. So it shouldn't be wp_ajax_st_24388029 in any case.

Comment: @pmandell Second parameter to `add_action('wp_ajax_{action}', 'custom_function_name')` can be anything you write. It doesn't need to be same as action name. :)